# MCMClogit confusion

Tags: r, bayesian, montecarlo, markov-chains, mcmc

Could anybody explain to me why

```
simulatedCase <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
simDf <- data.frame(CASE = simulatedCase)
posterior_m0 <<- MCMClogit(CASE ~ 1, data = simDf, b0 = 0, B0 = 1)
```

always results in a MCMC acceptance ratio of 0? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is the model formula, since [logistic regression models have no error term](http://old.nabble.com/Error-term-in-logistic-regression-td9155597.html). Thus you model `CASE ~ 1` should be replaced by something like `CASE ~ x` (the predictor variable `x` is mandatory). Here is your example, modified:

```
CASE <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
x <- 1:100
posterior_m0 <- MCMClogit (CASE ~ x, b0 = 0, B0 = 1)
classic_m0 <- glm (CASE ~ x,  family=binomial(link="logit"), na.action=na.pass)
```

So I think your problem is not related to the MCMCpack library (disclaimer: I have never used this package).

Comment: This code works, but it fits two variables, the intercept and the linear term for the dependence on x. What I originally intended was to use MCMClogit just to fit the intercept, without dependence on x (a weird scenario, I know...)..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling into this same problem :

It seems that the MCMClogit function cannot handle anything but B0=0 if your model only has an intercept.

If you add a covariate, then you can specify a precision just fine.

I would consider other packages (such as arm or rjags) if you really want to sample from this model. For a list of options available for Bayesian regression, see http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html